# Read info from a list and put in a map

Tags: java

I have the below code that reads information from two lists, and puts it in a map. I have close to 500 records, but I only see 75 records in the map. Please suggest what mistake I am making :(

```
private static Map<MyStore, List<String>> buildCache() {        
    for (MyStore myStores : myStoreList) {   //Contains a list of all the stores owned by me - has close to 600 stores.         
        for (HardwareInfo hardware : hardwareList) {    //Contains a list infrastructure information of these stores - These lists only have store number in common.
            if (myStores.getStoreNumber().equals(myStores.getStoreNumber())) {                      
                myCache.put(myStores, hardware.getHardwareInfo_East()); //myCache is a static map.
                myCache.put(myStores, hardware.getHardwareInfo_West());
                myCache.put(myStores,hardware.getHardwareInfo_South());
                myCache.put(myStores,hardware.getHardwareInfo_North());
                break;
            }

        }
    }


    for(Map.Entry<MyStore, List<String>> entry:myCache.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println("ENTRY IS: " +entry.getKey()+ " AND VALUE IS: " +entry.getValue());
    }

    return myCache;
}
}
```

Comment: Heap could be the way forward...

Comment: is this intentional, doesn't seem to make sense
    if (myStores.getStoreNumber().equals(myStores.getStoreNumber()))

Comment: Sorry its actually - if (myStores.getStoreNumber().equals(hardware.getStoreNumber())). This is just a skeleton of what I am implementing. I couldn't paste the real code here, so had to create some dummy objects to make my point :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Map` maps one key to one value. You're overriding the value many times.

This

```
if (myStores.getStoreNumber().equals(myStores.getStoreNumber())) {                      
    myCache.put(myStores, hardware.getHardwareInfo_East()); //myCache is a static map.
    myCache.put(myStores, hardware.getHardwareInfo_West());
    myCache.put(myStores,hardware.getHardwareInfo_South());
    myCache.put(myStores,hardware.getHardwareInfo_North());
    break;
}
```

is the same as

```
if (myStores.getStoreNumber().equals(myStores.getStoreNumber())) {                      
    myCache.put(myStores,hardware.getHardwareInfo_North());
    break;
}
```

If you want to combine all the lists, you could do this:

```
if (myStores.getStoreNumber().equals(myStores.getStoreNumber())) {                      
    myCache.put(myStores, new ArrayList<String>(hardware.getHardwareInfo_East())); //myCache is a static map.
    List<String> list = myCache.get(myStores);
    list.addAll(hardware.getHardwareInfo_West());
    list.addAll(hardware.getHardwareInfo_South());
    list.addAll(hardware.getHardwareInfo_North());
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks jilordo. However in my case, I have multiple values for each key in the map. Something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969501/use-of-hashmap-for-multiple-vales-of-keys-and-why. So I am trying to put store number + all the other values tagged with that store number inside the map. But as you can see, I am not successful :(

Comment: If you want to store multiple values per key, you should use a `MultiMap`, e.g. the one provided by Guava.

Comment: If I am not using a multimap, what would the solution be?

Comment: @user2624866: The solution I posted. As said, a `Map` can only map one key to one value. In this case, the value is a `List`, which can contain many entries. So each key can be mapped to one `List`, but not many lists.